From $\Lambda_k$ and $\Lambda$ to $\mu$ (or $\lambda$)
Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, $a_n \in \mathbb{C}$, $|a_n|\leq 1$. Let $\Lambda_k = \mu \ast \log^k$; in particular, $\Lambda_1$ equals the von Mangoldt function $\Lambda$. Suppose that we have asymptotics
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda_k(n) a_n = (c_k + \eta_k(x)) x \log^{k-1} x$$
for $2\leq k\leq 2\log \log x$ (say), where $\eta_k(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$. (EDIT: WillSawin's comments to his answer below show that one needs to require this at least for $$2\leq k\leq C \log \log x \log \log \log x,$$ not $2\leq k\leq 2 \log \log x$. Require the asymptotics in that broader range of $k$, then.)
Write $$S(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda(n) a_n.$$
One ought to be able to express $$M(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) a_n$$ in terms of $c_k$, $\eta_k$ and $S(x)$: if $S(x)$ is "too large", then, given $c_2$ and $\eta_2$, $\sum_{n\leq x} (\Lambda\ast \Lambda)(n)\; a_n$ will be smaller than expected (because $\Lambda_2 = \log \cdot \Lambda - \Lambda\ast \Lambda$), and so (given $c_3$ and $\eta_3$) $\sum_{n\leq x} (\Lambda \ast \Lambda \ast \Lambda)(n) a_n$ will be larger than expected, etc.
Is there an expression for $M(x)$ in terms of $c_k$, $\eta_k$ and $S(x)$? As you can see, the basic argument is straightforward, but weights will be annoying, and I do not want to reinvent the wheel. Chapter 16 in Opera de Cribro (on Bombieri's asymptotic sieve, as in Bombieri's "On twin almost primes") goes in this direction but is written in a way that is wedded to sieve assumptions.
In particular: if $S(x)$ is "off" (if, say, it's twice the expected asymptotic, or half), to what extent is this reflected in $M(x)$?
(Note: work with $F(x) = \sum_{n\leq x} \lambda(n) a_n$ instead of $M(x)$ if you prefer. Here $\lambda$ is the Liouville function.)

Just to be clear: of course there is an expression for $S(x)$ in terms of $M(y)$ , $y\leq x$ (by $\Lambda = \mu \ast \log$), without assumptions on $\sum_{n\leq x} \Lambda_k(n) a_n$. The problem is not that lower values of $y$ are used, but that that expression is lossy - it wastes two factors of $\log$.

You say "let $\lambda$ be" but then don't mention $\lambda$

@mathworker21 Noted, changed the phrasing.

How does the Dirichlet convolution structure give an expression for $S(x)$ in terms of $M(y)$? Is $a_n$ multiplicative?

@WillSawin Right, I was speaking loosely; it gives an expression for $S(x)$ in terms of $\sum_{n\leq x: d|n} a_n$. At any rate, that is what I am saying I do not want to do (though it is really the $\log^2$ loss incurred in that procedure that is the problem).

But if you have an answer to my original question in the case of $a_n$ multiplicative, be my guest!

I was concerned that an answer to the original question along the lines you want might not exist if you don't also have information on $\sum_{k \leq x/d} \Lambda_k(x) a_{nd}$. If that turns out to be the case, would you rather have a positive answer using asymptotics for $\sum_{k \leq x/d} \Lambda_k(x) a_{nd}$ or a negative answer to the original question?

I'd be glad to know both, but the first one would be more interesting.

... and again, it would be particularly interesting if one does not waste a factor, or at least if one wastes less than a $\log$. I don't think this approach should be wasteful (that's the entire point).

I think $a_n$ defined by
$$ a_n =\begin{cases} \mu(n) & \textrm{if } \omega(n) > \log \log n \\ 0 & \textrm{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ may be problematic. We have $M(x) \approx x \cdot (3/\pi^2)$ but all the other sums have a lot of cancellation.
To see this, I claim we have.
$$\sum_{\substack{ n \leq x \\  \omega(n) \geq \ell }} \Lambda_k (n)  \approx C_{k,\ell} x \log^{k-1} x  $$ where $$C_{k,\ell}= \sum_{\substack{ S \subseteq  \{2,\dots,k\}\\ |S| \geq \ell-1}} \prod_{i\in S}\frac{1}{i-1} $$
which follows by induction from the usual identity  $\Lambda_{k+1} = \log \cdot \Lambda_k + \Lambda * \Lambda_k$ since
$$\sum_{\substack{ n \leq x \\  \omega(n) \geq \ell }} \Lambda_k (n) \leq  \sum_{\substack{ n \leq x \\  \omega(n) \geq \ell }} \Lambda_{k-1} (n) \log n  + \sum_{ m \leq x} \Lambda(m) \sum_{\substack{ n \leq x/m \\  \omega(n) \geq \ell-1 }} \Lambda_{k-1} (n)$$
$$\leq \log x \sum_{\substack{ n \leq x \\  \omega(n) \geq \ell }} \Lambda_{k-1} (n)   + \sum_{ m \leq x} \Lambda(m) \sum_{\substack{ n \leq x/m \\  \omega(n) \geq \ell-1 }} \Lambda_{k-1} (n)$$
$$ \approx  C_{k-1,\ell} x \log^{k-1} x + \sum_{m \leq x} \Lambda(m)  C_{k-1,\ell-1} (x/m) \log^{k-2}(x/m) $$
$$ \approx C_{k-1,\ell} x \log^{k-1} x +   C_{k-1,\ell-1} x \log^{k-1}(x) / (k-1)$$
and then $C_{k,\ell}= C_{k-1,\ell} + C_{k-1,\ell-1}/(k-1)$ completes the induction step. (The base case uses that $C_{1,\ell}=1$ for all $\ell\leq 1$ which matches the left hand side where the condition $\omega(n)\geq \ell$ is trivial for these $\ell$.)
Now $C_{k,\ell} \leq \binom{k}{\ell} / (\ell-1)!$ which is very small for $\ell = \log \log x$ since $k$ is at most $2 \log \log x$ so $$\binom{k}{\ell} / (\ell-1)! \leq 2^{k}/ (\ell-1)! =  e^{ - \log \log x (\log \log \log x - O(1))} = \log x^{- (\log \log \log x - O(1))}$$
So we have more cancellation than any power of log in $\sum_{n \leq x} \Lambda_k(n) a_n$ but none in $M$.
I think this is problematic for what you want, unless you have a large amount of uniformity in $\eta_k$.

This is interesting, though what I was really wanted was in the opposite direction: that, if $M(x)$ is small, then (assuming that all the $c_k$'s are either $0$ or in some sense "consistent") $S(x)$ must be small. Or, otherwise put, that if $S(x)$ is large (think of $a_n$ as real), then (since $\sum_n \Lambda_2(n) a_n$ is given), $\sum_{n: \omega(n)=2} a_n$ has to be smaller than it would otherwise be, and so (since $\sum_n \Lambda_3(n) a_n$ is given), $\sum_{n: \omega(n)=3} a_n$ has to be larger than it would otherwise be, etc., thereby forcing $-M(x)$ to be large.

@HAHelfgott Suppose there exists an example where the phenomenon you describe occurs, in particular $S(x)$ is large and $-M(x)$ is large. Just add $a_n$ to a suitable constant multiple of $a_n$ from my example to make $M(x)$ small but keep $S(x)$ large.

I think I need an extra condition to formalize what I mean by "consistent" (which as a side effect would break such an easy counterexample). Can you give an example where $M(x)$ is small, $S(x)$ is large and all $c_k$'s are zero? That would be indicative of a serious issue.

@HAHelfgott I think $a_n = \begin{cases} \mu(n) & \textrm{if }\omega(n)<\log\log n \ -\mu(n) & \textrm{ if }\omega(n)>\log \log n \end{cases}$ does the trick: Average against $\mu(n)$ is small, average against $\Lambda(n)$ is large, and average against $\Lambda_k(n)$ agrees with average of $\Lambda_k(n)\mu(n)$ which I think is small for $k>1$.

Right, the average of $\Lambda_k(n) \mu(n)$ for $k>1$, $n\leq x$ is small compared to that of $\Lambda_k(n)$, in that it is not hard to see that it is $O((\log x)^{k-2})$ (is that the right size, or is it smaller?).  Hm, let me think and see what is going on there. Thanks. (PS. Obviously the average of $a_n \Lambda_k(n)$ won't agree with the average of $\Lambda_k(n) \mu(n)$ for $k>\log \log n$, but I'm not sure that that's enough to render your example harmless.)

@HAHelfgott In the function field setting the average of $\Lambda_k(n) \mu(n)$ is $O(1)$ and this is sharp. The calculations in my answer should show that the average of $a_n \Lambda_k(n)$ is still close to the average of $\mu(n)\Lambda_k(n)$ for $ k>\log\log n$ but $k= O(\log \log n)$.

@HAHelfgott There's a similar effect where you can have $\log x^{\log \log x}$ cancellation in $a(n) \Lambda * \Lambda(n)$, $a(n) \Lambda * \Lambda *\Lambda(n)$, and so on and still have $\sum_n a(n)\mu(n)$ large (or small).

I think that's what is going on is that you are running up a large "bill" for $\omega(n)<\log \log n$ (meaning that $a_n \mu(n)$ has a large average over those $n$) and then you are paying it off very slowly, so to speak. This is meaningful but not fatal, in that it shows that it is not enough to ask for asymptotics for $k = O(\log \log x)$, as I did; one needs to ask for them for $k = O(\log \log x \log \log \log x)$, at the very least. Not sure this is bad though it does change the question.

For what $a(n)$ do you have $(\log x)^{\log \log x}$ cancellation in $a(n) \Lambda\ast \Lambda(n)$, etc.?

@HaHelfgott Take $a(n)$ to be zero unless $\omega(n)$ is close to $\log \log n$ and the product of the $\omega(n)/2$ smallest prime factors of $n$ is less than $e^{ (\log n)^{2/3}}$. This is true for almost all numbers but is not true for most numbers weighted by $\Lambda * \dots * \Lambda$, which typically have prime factors mostly of similar sizes.

Now, that's interesting - and a more serious source for concern: one could define $a(n)$ obeying your condition for $n$ composite, and as $a(p)=1$ for $p$ prime, and still have $\sum_n a_n \mu(n)$ very small. Now, $|a(n)| \Lambda\ast \Lambda(n)$ is not as small as $(\log x)^{-\log \log x}$ on average; do you mean that you can choose $a(n)$ so that $a(n) \Lambda\ast \Lambda(n)$, etc., have lots of cancellation (besides having smallish support) while still obeying the conditions and keeping $\sum_n a_n \mu(n)$ small?

@HAHelfgott First for the version where you average $a_n$ against von Mangoldt correlations there's no interaction effect where average against $\Lambda$ large makes average against $\Lambda * \Lambda$ small, so there's no reason to expect the average against $\Lambda$ alone controls anything - you can just take $a_n =1$ for $n$ prime and $a_n=0$ otherwise and get no cancellation against $\Lambda$ but cancellation against any Dirichlet convolution with $\Lambda$.

@HAHelfgott Second, that's why I demand $\omega(n)$ close to $\log \log n$, which forces at least close to $\log \log n$ copies of $\Lambda$ (restricting $n$ to squarefree as we can assume). For a $\Lambda$-weighted prime to be smaller than $e^{\log(n)^{2/3}}$ is very unlikely, with probability like $\log(n)^{-1/3}$, and we have $\log \log n/2$ primes that have to be that small, and none of the other factors substantially mitigate this.

Not sure I understand your 'first', but I agree with your 'second' - thanks. But wait, demanding $\omega(n)$ close to $\log \log n$ except for $n$ prime won't work, as then the average against $\Lambda_2$, etc., won't be small.

@HAHelfgott This is for the version where I demand the averages against $\Lambda * \Lambda  $ and so on are small, not $\Lambda_2$ and $\Lambda_3$ and so on are small. The point of this is to suggest an obstruction to the strategy of using information about $\Lambda_k$ to obtain information about convolutions of $\Lambda$ and finally obtain information about Möbius. But I don't mean to assume averages against the $\Lambda_k$ are controlled in this setting. I can probably do something where both the $\Lambda_k$ and $\Lambda^{*k}$ are controlled but it would be more complicated.

I think one may be able to construct a truly harmful counterexample by combining one of your first $a_n$'s with your more recent observation: let $a_n = \mu(n)$ for $\omega(n) < \log \log x$, and, for $n$ with $\omega(n) > \log \log x$, balance things by letting $a_n = -\mu(n)$ for almost all $n$ (so that $\sum_n a_n \mu(n)$ is small) but letting $a_n = \mu(n)$ for $n$ having mainly large prime factors (that is, most $n$ when weighted by $\Lambda_k$ with $\log \log x\lll k \ll \log \log x \log \log \log x$; let $a_n$ be supported on $n$ with $n\ll \log \log x$ to simplify).
